# SharePoint 2010 Reporting Services Integrated-mode Error

Tags: silverlight, sharepoint, reporting-services, sharepoint-2010, performancepoint

I am running SharePoint 2010 and Reporting Services 2008 R2 SharePoint integrated-mode. I am able to browse to the reportserver site : http://DBserver/reportserver which lists my site collections and I am able to get to the document library which holds my reports. However, when I try opening a report I get the following error:

Report Server has encountered a SharePoint error. (rsSharePointError)
The security validation for this page is invalid. Click Back in your Web browser, refresh the page, and try your operation again.
For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote errors

I am able to resolve that issue by going to Central Admin, Application Management, General Settings and turning Web Page Security Validation Off. But if I do that I get an error when using silverlight features like site, or list creation.

Any ideas?